# c# - способы представления конечных точек отрезка на плоскости для нахождения его середины

Tags: c#

Есть задача на нахождение середины отрезка. Как объявить точки отрезка?

Например, точка а = 3.1,5.5. Как синтаксически правильно объявить?

Comment: А чем не катят две `double`-переменные?

Comment: катят, просто там скобки не походят, фигурные и квадратные тоже, и без скобок тоже не принимает. я начинаю изучать язык, поэтому непонятно так

Comment: @Juice установите R#, изучать язык станет сразу гораздо проще.

Comment: спасибо, а что насчет самого вопроса ?))

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вам фигурные скобки? И квадратные?

Comment: `var a = new {x = 3.1, y = 5.5};` создает анонимный объект с `x` и `y` типа `double`

Comment: @Oleg: А зачем так сложно — анонимный объект? Покамест из изложенного ТС'ом ему достаточно просто две переменные.

Comment: @VladD: Что может быть проще, чем анонимный объект? Напомню, что вопрос был задан о точке с двумя координатами, а две переменные разделяют информацию.

Comment: @Oleg: Анонимный объект сложновато передать на обработку в другую функцию, например. Ну и покамест не вижу необходимости в _объекте_.

Comment: @Oleg: Пока задача настолько проста, абстракция объекта кажется мне излишне тяжеловесной. Потому что если мы вводим класс для точки, следующим шагом вы предложите вводить класс для отрезка, да? Объекты нужны не ради объектов, а для уменьшения сложности. А покамест такой необходимости не видно.

Comment: @VladD: "передать на обработку в другую функцию" или венуть из из фунци всьма посто. Самое сложное - это использовние витальной русской клавиатуры.

Comment: @Oleg: Собирался уж поспорить, но ваш комментарий сам является отличным доказательством изложенного в нём тезиса. Так что вы меня убедили :)

Comment: @VladD:  `var o1 = new { x = 3.1, y = 5.5 }; var o2 = new { x = 4.2, y = 3.5 }; var middle = new {x = (o1.x + o2.x)/2, y = (o1.y + o2.y)/2}; Console.WriteLine(middle);` или `var a1 = new[] { 3.1, 5.5 }; var a2 = new[] { 4.2, 3.5 }; var middle = new[] { (x[0] + y[0]) / 2, (x[1] + y[1]) / 2 }; Console.WriteLine("{{ x = {0}, y = {1} }}", middle[0], middle[1]);` - эта два варианта, которые, возможно хотел у получить Juice. "передать на обработку в другую функцию" приработе с анонимными типами легко если использовать `object`.

Comment: @Oleg: Ну, передать как `object` можно, но выковыривать оттуда значения в самой функции придётся через рефлексию.

Comment: @VladD: Более сложно лишь чтение полей, например, `public static double GetDoublePropByName(object a, string propertyName) { return (double)a.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(a, null); }`. Есть другие варианты с использованием `dynamic` и `ExpandoObject`, но все это дискуссии на пустом месте. Я написал в предыдущем комментарии чего, я полагаю, ожидал Juice, задавший вопрос.

Comment: @Oleg: Я думаю, у ТС проблемы с базовым синтаксисом, так что предлагать решение с рефлексией или DLR скорее всего не подойдёт. (Оставим в стороне размышления о целесообразности и эффективности.)

Comment: @VladD Juice написал в одном из коментариев: "вот такое задание, чтобы не мучал) Написать программу, вычисляющую и выводящую на экран обе координаты середины отрезка между точками 3.5, 2.7 и 8.5, 9.1." Поэтому я и полагал не мучить его сложными конструкциямт и предложить var o1 = new { x = 3.1, y = 5.5 }; var o2 = new { x = 4.2, y = 3.5 }; var middle = new {x = (o1.x + o2.x)/2, y = (o1.y + o2.y)/2}; Console.WriteLine(middle);

Comment: @Igor: см. мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @Oleg: То же самое можно было бы куда проще написать как `double x1 = 3.1, x2 = ...;`. А так для понимания вашего кода нужно знать понятие анонимного объекта.

Comment: @VladD: вы спрашивали о передаче анонимных типов в качестве параметра и их возвращении из функции. Попробуйте следующее `public static object GetMiddleDynamic(dynamic a, dynamic b) { return new { x = (a.x + b.x) / 2, y = (a.y + b.y) / 2 }; } ` and `public static void Main() { var o1 = new { x = 3.5, y = 2.7 }; var o2 = new { x = 8.5, y = 9.1 }; var o3 = GetMiddleDynamic(o1, o2); Console.WriteLine(o4); }`.

Comment: @Oleg: Ну да, DLR работает. Но вы теряете проверку типов времени компиляции: если в функцию `GetMiddleDynamic` передать, допустим, строку, то ошибка обнаружится лишь во время выполнения.

Answer (score 5):

Вы сейчас думаете не над теми вещами. Выражаясь образно, вы сейчас похожи на человека, которому надо покрасить забор - и он ходит, пристает к прохожим: "подскажите пожалуйста, в какой руке кисть держать?". Да в любой!

Можно объявить переменные так:

```
double x1, y2, x2, y2;
```

Можно так:

```
double X1, X2, Y1, Y2;
```

Или так:

```
double x1 = ...;
double y1 = ...;
double x2 = ...;
double y2 = ...;
```

Или даже так:

```
double a, b, c, d;
```

Или вот так:

```
double Икс1, Игрек1, Икс2, Игрек2;
```

Ну или, как советуют выше, так:

```
struct Point { 
  public double x, y;
}

Point A, B;
```

Для начала, вам надо достигнуть того уровня, на котором вы вообще не думаете - какие в программе будут переменные и в каком количестве. Нужна переменная - заводите ее. Не нужна - удаляете. Только после этого можно начинать задумываться над семантически и стилистически правильными способами заведения переменных. Потому что, при всей важности, задача эта - вспомогательная.

Нельзя на вспомогательные задачи (заведение переменных) тратить больше времени, чем на основную. Пока вы ждете ответ на свой вопрос, вы могли бы уже 6 раз решить эту задачу шестью разными способами :)

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете упростить себе работу, если возьмете за основу определение структуры `PointF`, определенную в пространстве имен `System.Drawing`. Для этого вам нужно в проект подключить ссылку на `System.Drawing`.

Вы можете либо непосредственно использовать эту структуру, либо создать свою структуру по аналогии данной структуры. По крайней мере вы можете перенять многие методы и операторы.

Вам останется создать структуру, которую вы можете назвать, например, `Vector` или `Segment`, или как вы сами хотите, которая будет состоять из двух точек. В эту структуру вам следует включить метод, который находит длину отрезка.

Чтобы получить точку середины отрезка, достаточно будет прибавить к его начальной точке половину длины отрезка.

Answer (score 3):

```
public sealed class Point
{
   public double X { get;set;}
   public double Y { get;set;}
}

var point = new Point{ X = 3.1, Y = 5.5};

public sealed class Line
{
    public Point A {get;set;}
    public Point B {get;set;}
}

var line = new Line
{
    A = new Point{ X = 3.1, Y = 5.5},
    B = new Point{ X = 3.1, Y = 5.5}
}
```

Comment: А почему `float`, а не `double`?

Comment: а sealed, это что-то типо наследования?

Comment: double тоже можно

Comment: @Juice нет, это значит, что от этого класса нельзя унаследоваться.

Comment: @VladD поменял на `double`, и правда будет лучше.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов а если там отрезок, и на каждом конце по 2 координаты, тогда как быть?

Comment: @Juice: Например, попробуйте завести две точки :)

Comment: вот такое задание, чтобы не мучал) Написать программу, вычисляющую и выводящую на экран обе координаты середины отрезка между точками 3.5, 2.7 и 8.5, 9.1.

Comment: @VladD, а почему `double`, а не `float`?

Comment: @ixSci: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/188725/6802 Это нативный тип с плавающей точкой. Остальные медленнее, и нужны только при особых обстоятельствах.

Comment: @VladD, весьма неубедительно. Не вижу причины выбирать double, когда достаточно float. Это как «всегда используйте int64»

Comment: @VladD, что значит «нативный тип с плавающей точкой»?

Comment: ребят а что насчет задачи?:))))

Comment: @Juice добавил пример с отрезком

Comment: @МстиславПавлов вы решили?

Comment: @Juice - Вы руками-то можете посчитать какой будет ответ?

Comment: @Juice что решил? :)

Comment: @ixSci: Дело в том, что вычисления с типом `double` на текущих системах выполняются быстрее, эффективнее и точнее (само собой разумеется), чем с `float`. Хуже того, оптимизирующий компилятор часто проводит вычисления на `float` реально в `double`, и лишь потом обрезает конечный результат до `float`. Причина примерно та же, как и при выборе между `int` и `char`.

Comment: @ixSci: Хм, интернет сообщает, что в Intel'овских процессорах нативный floating-тип имеет 80 бит, что даже шире, чем `double`.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов задачу)) у меня с руки ответ 5.95 получился)) вы скажите ответ. если знаете, чтобы я знал протсо))

Comment: @Juice - так вроде два числа должно быть.

Comment: @Igor одно же, там же одна середина) или я забыл что-то?) запутался

Comment: @Juice - Середина там точно одна. Вы в каком классе учитесь?

Comment: @VladD, да с чего Вы взяли, что double быстрее? Как Вы уже сами указали, x87 имеет 80-битную разрядность. Так что конвертация происходит как для double, так и для float. Но float в два раза меньше, а это значит, что в одну кэш линию влазит больше float, за одну векторную инструкцию можно обработать больше float'ов и т.д.

Comment: @ixSci: Окей, утверждение о том, что `double` быстрее, возможно, устарело. Но в любом случае заменив `double` на `float` вы просто так теряете точность. Поскольку внутри оба типа расширяются до 80 бит, думаю, аргумент насчёт cache line для промежуточных вычислений точно так же устарел. (В любом случае, если мы уж говорим об низкоуровневых оптимизациях на уровне размера кэша, речь должна идти о числомолотилке, которой у ТС не наблюдается.) Так что `float` нужен только если чисел **настолько** много, что они не влазят в память, и нужно экономить.

Comment: @VladD, точность это тоже требование системы, разве нет? Я не вижу ни одной причины, почему double должен использоваться по умолчанию, когда есть float. Ну и аргумент про cache line не только не устарел, это одна из наиболее насущных проблем сейчас. Cache friendly data structure сейчас важны как никогда.

Comment: @ixSci: Насчёт cache friendly это нужно лишь для очень узкого и ограниченного класс задач. Современное программирование совсем не про низкоуровневые оптимизации.

Comment: @ixSci: Окей, пойдём с начала. Вы не будете спорить с тем, что нужно использовать `int` для индексов, хотя в принципе можно было бы обойтись и `char`'ом? (Или вообще битовым полем на 4 бита, экономия!)

Comment: @VladD, давайте без аналогий, мы вроде про конкретные вещи говорим? int это совершенно другое, всё API построено на int(size_t для C++), поэтому это сравнение не верно. Ну а насчёт современного программирования: вы заблуждаетесь, давно были на конференциях или смотрели видео с них? Посмотрите, очень полезно. CppCon 2015, к примеру, рекомендую. Ну и я думаю, что нет смысла продолжать, я так и не увидел, почему я должен предпочесть double float'у. Всё остальное это переливание из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: @ixSci: Я на конференции по C++ не ездил, каюсь. Но я вижу, что числомолотилки занимают ничтожную часть реально производимого софта, так что технические тонкости, которыми гордятся участники конференции, обычно нужны только им самим. Sad but true.

Comment: @ixSci: А по поводу float vs double, повторю свой тезис: теряется сразу точность, а выигрыш потенциален и реально заметен лишь в узкой сфере применения. Аналогия с char/int прямая: там тоже внутри всё равно используется тип размером в процессорное слово, так что по скорости почти всё равно. Но при этом меньше int'ов помещаются в cache line.

Comment: Коллеги, хватит холиварить, На х86 быстрее флоаты, на х64 чутку быстрее double.

Comment: @ixSci _"Я не вижу ни одной причины, почему double должен использоваться по умолчанию, когда есть float"_ -- float был в WinForms.. а в WPF используется double. поэтому в WPF нет смысла определять float. и можно сказать что double используется по умолчанию.

Comment: @Stack, если какая-то библиотека использует определённый тип это значит, что для операций с этой библиотекой лучше придерживаться этого типа, вот и всё. Все остальные слои программы, а также не-WPF программы не выигрывают от double ничего

Comment: @ixSci на современных процессорах double быстрее, т.к. они оптимизированы под работу с этим типом данных. float имеет смысл использовать на мобильных платформах(и то не на всех) и в тех случаях, когда софт пишется для чего то допотопного.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, можно ссылку на доказательство Вашего утверждения?

Comment: @ixSci Шилдт Java 8 Полное руководство. Страница 79.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, не, так не пойдёт. Шилдт это вообще не авторитет, далеко не.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738448/is-float-slower-than-double-does-64-bit-program-run-faster-than-32-bit-program), к примеру, почитайте.

Comment: @ixSci а какой юзер с SO авторитетнее автора книги?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, AnT привёл объяснение, почему double не может быть быстрее. В других ответах народ измерял и многие разницы не нашли. Шилдт болтун, которому нет веры. Как он объясняет свою позицию? Что такого появилось в x86-64, чего не было в x86? Разве там FPU изменился?

Comment: @ixSci предлагаю рассмотреть этот вопрос как полагается: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483591/float-vs-double-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

> Есть задача на нахождение середины отрезка. Как объявить точки отрезка?

Можно использовать класс Line, в котором указывают координаты начала и конца отрезка, через свойства X1,Y1 и X2,Y2.

---

Ниже пример использования Line в программе, которая выводит два отрезка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "WindowsBase"

using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

var c = new Canvas { Width=300, Height=150, Background=Brushes.WhiteSmoke };
c.Children.Add(new Line { X1=50, Y1=5, X2=140, Y2=140, Stroke=Brushes.Blue });
c.Children.Add(new Line { X1=20, Y1=110, X2=270, Y2=50, Stroke=Brushes.Red });    
var w = new Window() { SizeToContent=SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight, Content=c };
w.ShowDialog();
```

---

Точку пересечения отрезков или пересечение других геометрических фигур можно получить с помощью CombinedGeometry, пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483494).

Comment: за что минус? хотите сказать, что на практике используете что-то другое? :) кстати, у вопроса нет тега "образование".

Comment: @Abyx _"ответ никак не помогает решить исходную задачу"_ -- а вы знаете задачу? а другие ответы помогают? или вы другие ответы не видите? :)

Comment: @Abyx _"Задача - в заголовке вопроса, пожалуйста внимательно прочитайте его еще раз"_ -- так Line - это и есть "способ представления конечных точек отрезка".

Comment: Я не минусовал, но: мне кажется, суть ответа («используйте готовый класс `Line`») слишком завуалирована, спрятана за избыточным кодом и графикой. Отсюда наверное и минусы.

Comment: @VladD _" слишком завуалирована"_ -- да было под цитатой в одну строку, а дальше сразу про код. изменил ответ. отделил про Line от примера. а минусы, как я понял - это эмоции. из-за того, что кто-то что-то не заметил. и бывает, что минусы в вопросе, например, о c# ставят те, у кого c# не указан в профиле.