# Почему семантика и системы типов очень важны?

Tags: информатика, семантика, теория-типов

Я слышал, что знания семантики и систем типов очень важны для любого программиста. Но я не понимаю почему. Может они важны только для теоретиков или разработчиков компиляторов? В свой практике я никогда не думаю о семантике или системах типов глубоко. Про семантику мне вполне хватает знаний что она определяет смысл синтаксических конструкций. Когда я пишу + я знаю что он сложит мне 2 числа. И этого мне достаточно. Про системы типов... когда я пишу `int i` мне достаточно знать что i теперь может быть целым числом. ну и еще полезны конечно знания о том что такое статическая, динамическая, строгая, слабая системы типов. Когда этих знаний может стать недостаточно? Когда могут потребоваться более глубокие знания о семантики и системах типов в повседневной практике программиста?

Comment: _"знания семантики и систем типов очень важны для любого программиста."_ -- если не обращать внимание на существующие типы и семантику, то можно создать целую фабрику своих велосипедов.

Comment: @Stack, обращать внимание надо, но что значит обращать внимание? Если тебе нужно вычесть перемножить 2 числа а ты пишешь + или нужно как то представить имя человека и ты пишешь int name - то это наверное не очень хорошо) но на такие то вещи я думаю все обращают внимание. Ну и если нужна например, как можно более надежная программа, то вряд ли стоит выбирать язык с динамической системой типов. Или вы еще что то имеете в виду когда говорите "обращать внимание"?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/308272

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров _"Если тебе нужно вычесть перемножить 2 числа"_ -- в такой микроситуации не надо. но лучше знать что уже есть, чтобы не тратить время на велосипеды. пример тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Статические анализаторы** делают на основе *формальной* (программы иначе не могут) семантики языка выводы о программе, давая возможность *находить некоторые виды ошибок в автоматическом режиме*, ускоряя процесс разработки/стабилизации программного продукта.

  Сейчас эту же функцию часто выполняют компиляторы (ведь они всё равно разбирают исходный код программы, поэтому могут выполнять эту задачу с минимумом велосипедов) своими *предупреждениями* (warnings), но строго говоря, к самому процессу компиляции это слабо относится.
- **Процедуры рефакторинга**, в том числе производимые вручную. Возможность *доказать* (хотя бы для себя), что некое преобразование не изменяет код, даёт возможность вести процесс увереннее и быстрее, не вникая во все детали реализации; вплоть до осуществления его *автоматически* в средах разработки (если удалось получить формальное доказательство).

  Отсутствие этой возможности замедляет рефакторинг или вовсе приводит к отказу от него, что ведёт к постепенному увеличению сложности поддержки кода, что снижает производительность разработчиков при дальнейшей работе с ним.
- Как правило, в сообществах программистов (в проекте, у технологии, где-то ещё) принимается некий **стилевой стандарт** (style guide) для кода. И делается это не только затем, чтобы другие члены этого же сообщества испытывали меньше затруднений с чтением написанного в сообществе кода, но и для продвижения **безопасных практик**, использование которых **снижает риск ошибок** (и экономит время на их отладку). Чтобы эти практики выработать, необходимо понять семантику языка (но необязательно осознать это!).